# Mac Yosmite: Set macports Apache as default (opt/local/apache2) on localhost rather than OSX distribution

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've installed Apache via macports, it worked fine for a while, but suddenly for some reason it switched back to using the default OSX distribution of Apache located in (private/etc/apache2), quite loopy stuff. Macports php is `5.6.4` while OSX is `5.5.1`.

`which php` returns this:
/opt/local/bin/php

`php --version` returns:
5.6.4

... but localhost php info returns `5.5.14`

I run `httpd -V` and I get this:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep  9 2014 14:48:20
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:31
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

How do I set which Apache is used on Localhost?
Seems I have conflicting ports: `Can't install apache because conflicting ports are active: apache2`

Comment: I tried setting OSX apache to **Listen 127.0.0.1:8888** and it continued to work at the new port, however Macports apache at localhost:80 still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the "wrong" apache and remove the httpd.conf file for it. 
Start the "Right" apache and be sure that it uses Listen 127.0.0.1 (httpd.conf about line 41) and that it point to the correct ServerRoot, '/usr in this case, or "/opt/local" in my case. Then mace sure all the directories needed are correct in http.conf and on all the other conf files there are.

Comment: Correct, I stopped the OSX apache with **sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k stop** then started macports with **sudo bash -x /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start** and it worked.